# NuGet Error:Unable to find version '2.4.8' of package 'OpenCV.ffmpeg.overlay-x64_v110'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opencv, nuget

I've encountered a strange problem during  development.

I added the OpenCVSharp and OpenCV.net packages into my C# project in Visual Studio 2017 using Nuget.

However, I got this error while building:

> NuGet Error:Unable to find version '2.4.8' of package
>   'OpenCV.ffmpeg.overlay-x64_v110'

So I removed the packages from the project because they're unnecessary but the error still exists.

I tried in many ways but I can't fix this problem.

Comment: l think the package [OpenCV.ffmpeg.overlay-x64_v110](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCV.ffmpeg.overlay-x64_v110/) is deprecated  by the author and there is no link for this package. l think you should uninstall it at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

> So I removed packages from the project because they're unnecessary
>   honestly but the error still exists.
>
> I tried in many ways but I can't fix this problem.

Please see the [OpenCV.ffmpeg.overlay-x64_v110' nuget package description](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCV.ffmpeg.overlay-x64_v110/).

***The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore.***

Since 2014, the package can not be used any more** and the author has abandoned this nuget package. So you can't reference the nuget package that no longer exists. To solve it, you must uninstall it in VS2017 at the same time.

**Solution**:

**Update 1**

You can try these two ways:

1) uninstall it by nuget management UI.

Right-click on your project-->**Mangament Nuget Packages**-->**Install** -->choose the related nuget to uninstall it.

2) uninstall it by modifing files

delete the content in packages.config like

```
  <package id="OpenCV.ffmpeg.overlay-x64_v110" version="2.4.8" targetFramework="xxx" />
```

then also delete the content in the xxx.csproj file like

```
<Reference Include="OpenCV.ffmpeg.overlay-x64_v110,Version=2.4.8,xxxxxxxxx">
<HintPath>.....</HintPath>
....
</Reference>
```

**Or** you can remove the itemgroup in the xxxxx.csproj just like

```
<Reference Include="OpenCV.ffmpeg.overlay-x64_v110,Version=2.4.8,xxxxxxxxx"></Reference>
```

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Since [OpenCV.ffmpeg.overlay-x64_v110](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCV.ffmpeg.overlay-x64_v110/) is no longer maintained by the author and is abandoned since 2014. We recommend you should uninstall this nuget package.